# keras cannot train model due to numpy shape tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am a novice and I am trying to train my model with Keras. I have 14 classes.

Here are the shapes of my training and test data:

```
print('train data shape:', X_train.shape)
print('one hot shape:', y_train.shape)
print('one hot shape:', y_test.shape)
print('Number of images in x_train', x_train.shape[0])
print('Number of images in x_test', x_test.shape[0])
```

Output:

```
train data shape: (77623, 28, 28, 1)
one hot shape: (77623, 14, 14)
one hot shape: (500, 14, 14)
Number of images in x_train 77623
Number of images in x_test 500
```

Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


print(model.summary())
```

Model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_58 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_59 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_27 (MaxPooling (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_53 (Dropout)         (None, 12, 12, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_27 (Flatten)         (None, 9216)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_52 (Dense)             (None, 128)               1179776   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_54 (Dropout)         (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_53 (Dense)             (None, 14)                1806      
=================================================================
Total params: 1,200,398
Trainable params: 1,200,398
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

and here is the call to `fit` method:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=0,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), callbacks=[TQDMNotebookCallback()])
```

but I get this error:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_53 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (77623, 14, 14)
```

Comment: the one-hot encoded shape for your training labels should be (77623, 14), not (77623, 14, 14), how exactly did you get this data into this shape?

Comment: yes the  data were already on "one hot " shape so I make it still as at the begining

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to put your `input_shape=(28,28,1)` because your images are 28x28 gray scale

Answer (score 0):

Check your output shape: it should be `(num_samples, classes)`, not `(num_samples, 14, 14)`.